# What is the equivalent of the "Days" function or number of days between 2 dates in excel 2007?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I get the #NAME? error when I use the Days() function because the formula was built in Excel 2016 and it was probably not present in Excel 2007 yet. The error is shown:
[image: Error]

Originally, the formula suddenly had a xlfn appear before the function, I do not know why so I removed it. 
[image: Original Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These all produce the same result.

```
=AE2-AD2
=DATEDIF(AD2, AE2, "d")
=DAYS(AE2, AD2)
```

If you need to add 1 to make the count inclusive then just tack on `+1`or use,

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(AD2, AE2, "0000000")
```

Comment: `NETWORKDAYS.INTL` is not available in Excel 2007 but `NETWORKDAYS` can be used.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=DATEDIF(date1,date2,"d")
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the alternative. It's =datedif(AD2,AE2,"d")+1.